# How to change the colors in a bar chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors

I am trying to obtain a graph in blue colors, and I am obtain a graph in green.

My data is:

```
 lang <- c('spanish','italian','mix','english','portugues','others','french')
 n <- c(22689,754,510,410,256,128,55)
 percentage <- c(91.49,3.04,2.06,1.65,1.03,3.47,0.22)  

 count_bylanguage_top = data.frame(lang,n,percentage)
```

I am using this code:

```
pie <- ggplot(count_bylanguage_top, aes(x = "", y=n, fill =   factor(lang))) + 
geom_bar(width = 1, stat = "identity") +
scale_fill_brewer(palette="blues") + 
theme(axis.line = element_blank(), 
    plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5)) + 
labs(fill="lang", 
   x=NULL, 
   y=NULL, 
   title="Distribution of languages", 
   caption="Total Tweets with #Dante2018 hashtag")

pie + coord_polar(theta = "y", start=0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use "Blues" instead of "blues". In general, all of the palettes that come with the ggplot2 package are capitalized (see http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_brewer.html#palettes or http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/5312_98fc1aba2d5740dd849a5ab797cc2c8d.html)

As for your code, try:

```
pie <- ggplot(count_bylanguage_top, aes(x = "", y=n, fill =   factor(lang))) + 
geom_bar(width = 1, stat = "identity") +
scale_fill_brewer(palette="Blues") + # use Blues here
theme(axis.line = element_blank(), 
    plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5)) + 
labs(fill="lang", 
   x=NULL, 
   y=NULL, 
   title="Distribution of languages", 
   caption="Total Tweets with #Dante2018 hashtag")

pie + coord_polar(theta = "y", start=0)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I have already corrected in my code.

Comment: Glad to help! Thanks for posting a reproducible example.